# Execute rest of the function after async function is finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

i want to retrieve the last 4 digits of a payment using Stripe. for that i have to run an async function and inside this function another async function.
afterwards i want to update the db with the last4 digits. but i want to update the db after these 2 functions are resolved if not i get an `undefined`.

```
if (intent.status === "succeeded") {
    const user = res.locals.decodedClaims;
    const uid = user.uid;
    let last4; //trying to set last4 to global var so that i can change it inside a function

    // The payment didn’t need any additional actions and completed!
    // Handle post-payment fulfillment

    //get payment last4 digits
    stripe.paymentIntents.retrieve(intent.id, function(err, paymentIntent) {
      // asynchronously called
      if (err) {
        return console.log("PI retrieve error: ", err);
      }
      stripe.charges.retrieve(paymentIntent.charges.data[0].id, function(
        err,
        charge
      ) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log("Charge retrieve error: ", err);
        }
        last4 = charge.payment_method_details.card.last4;
        console.log("charge: ", last4); // works, eg: 4242
      });
    });

    //update status in database
    const userRef = db.collection("users").doc(uid);
    let updatedStatus = userRef.update({
      paid: true,
      last4: last4 //undefined
    });

    updatedStatus.catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
    //send success message to client
    return {
      success: true,
      hello: 1
    };
```

expected result:

```
//update status in database
    const userRef = db.collection("users").doc(uid);
    let updatedStatus = userRef.update({
      paid: true,
      last4: last4 //undefined
    });

    updatedStatus.catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
    //send success message to client
    return {
      success: true,
      hello: 1
```

all this runs after i get the value of last4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the most important part of JS here. Javascript is asynchronous. So, while your code is going through those 2 async calls, your `userRef.update()` also gets called at the same time. That's why you are getting undefined. Moreover, your return isn't really going to help you if this all is happening inside a function. It would always return success since it is working asynchronously.

Look into the below code. You need to return a Promise so that your function waits for all the async functions to return the responses.

```
yourFunction() {
return new Promise ( function(resolve, reject) {
if (intent.status === "succeeded") {
    const user = res.locals.decodedClaims;
    const uid = user.uid;
    let last4; //trying to set last4 to global var so that i can change it inside a function

    // The payment didn’t need any additional actions and completed!
    // Handle post-payment fulfillment

    //get payment last4 digits
    stripe.paymentIntents.retrieve(intent.id, function(err, paymentIntent) {
      // asynchronously called
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
     }
      stripe.charges.retrieve(paymentIntent.charges.data[0].id, function(
        err,
        charge
      ) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        last4 = charge.payment_method_details.card.last4;
        console.log("charge: ", last4); // works, eg: 4242
        //update status in database
        const userRef = db.collection("users").doc(uid);
        let updatedStatus = userRef.update({
          paid: true,
          last4: last4 //undefined
        });

        updatedStatus.catch(err => {
          reject(err);
        });
        //send success message to client
        resolve({
          success: true,
          hello: 1
        });
      });
    });


});
```

After this, you can call your function like

```
myFunction().then(function(success) {
   // your {success: true, hello: 1} comes here
}).catch(function(err)) {
   // all the errors come here.
}
```

If you want to use async/await instead, simply define your main function so that its `async functionName() {}`.
Then, do the following:

```
try {
  selectedPlan = await Stripe.plans.retrieve(stripePlanId); // use stripe's functions here.
} catch (error) {
  // error handling
}
```

Comment: can't do that, because i've a lot of `if else` statement in that function and i dont want to mess it up. isn't there a way that i only make it async await inside the if statement mentioned above?

Comment: In that case, you can just do the async/await for all the calls you make. Then, all of your code should be fine.